# Can one change import urls?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design

I need to use the [Ownable](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/ownership/Ownable.sol) contract from Open Zeppelin. Something like:

`import 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/master/contracts/ownership/Ownable.sol';`

Is there a way of defining a `setOwnableImportPath` function so I can change the url path if the library codebase is shuffled around?

Comment: Import statements are not changeable, import statements should be above of contract.

Answer (score 1):

As far I know, you can't change path of imports based on method. If you feel some thing might change in feature then download that file locally and import local file.

For more details check solidity document

http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/layout-of-source-files.html